# Redirect to login page once Refresh in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have developed an application in angular js with login authentication.
I have a requirement that, once user Refresh the page, application should redirect to login page.
How to achieve this ?

I tried with $location event i.e. 
**$locationChangeStart** 
But above event also gets fired when route of application changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window.onbeforeunload on .run method

```
myAPp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $cookies) {

    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.location.href = '/login';
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `onbeforeunload`,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.location.href = '/login';
}
```

which should be triggered when either the back/forward/refresh buttons are clicked to perform an action, unfortunately you can't tell if they are going back or forward.

Comment: no,i believe It wont work for SPA. I tried but not working.
any other solution ??

Comment: I tried with `location.href = '/login';` in angular app. It works for me.  But in my case, i use `$window` instead of window.

Comment: but where should I put this code ??? in .run() method ?? or somewhere else? I tried on run method not working.

Comment: yes, you can put this code in plan javascript script tag. Also for better maintainability, you can put it in `.run` method where you can use `$window` instead of `window`